# Button click event firing multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button echoed from a php file.
When i click that button it fires multiple times. Why is it behave like that?

I did some solutions i found here in stackoverflow but they did not work.
Any suggestions and corrections?

```
$(document).on('click','#reserve',function(){
      if (myclid != '0') {
        if (ll.charAt(0)=='b') {
            alert(lnk2);
            $.ajax({
              url: "reserve_func.php",
              method: "POST",
              data: {reserve_id:random_numbers, myclid:myclid, myclient:myclient, lnk2:lnk2, clid:clid},
              success: function(data) {
                  if (data == 'true') {

                    getResDate();
                  } else if (data== 'exceeded') {

                      pop();
                      $('#notice').html('Client <b style="text-transform: capitalize;">'+myclient +'</b> has two (2) lots that were still reserved and are not yet paid.');
                  }  else {

                      pop();
                      $('#notice').html(data);
                  }  
              }
            });
        }
      } else if (myclid=='0') {

        $('#pop_bg').fadeIn('fast');
        $('#pop_c').slideDown('fast');
        $('#notice').fadeIn('fast');
        $('#notice').html('Please select a client!');
      } else {

        $('#pop_bg').fadeIn('fast');
        $('#pop_c').slideDown('fast');
        $('#notice').fadeIn('fast');
        $('#notice').html('Please add your client first! Click <a href="profile.php">here</a> and then select <b>My client(s)');
      }
});
```

Comment: Is the button a `submit` button? If so use `event.preventDeault()` to stop the form submitting as well as your AJAX running

Comment: @RiggsFolly nope. It was a <button> tag

Comment: SO not a `<button type="submit"...>`

Comment: yup. here it is '<button id="reserve">Reserve</button>'

Comment: You're listening for the 'click' event on the document, which means that the 'click' will be heard firing on every ancestor of the element as it propagates through the document up to the document itself.

Comment: <button> is type submit by default

Comment: **where's the HTML for all this?** and what's the relation to "php" here? there's no code to support the question. If this is php-related, then edit your question to contain that code or remove the tag for it. Look at your developer console and if it's a php error; use error reporting.

Comment: @RiggsFolly it's all guesswork ^

Answer (score -1):

Please check this.

```html
$( "#reserve" ).on( "click", function( event ) {
 event.preventDefault();
 var install = $('#gt').val();
      if (myclid != '0') {
        if (ll.charAt(0)=='b') {
            alert(lnk2);
            $.ajax({
              url: "reserve_func.php",
              method: "POST",
              data: {reserve_id:random_numbers, myclid:myclid, myclient:myclient, lnk2:lnk2, clid:clid},
              success: function(data) {
                  if (data == 'true') {

                    getResDate();
                  } else if (data== 'exceeded') {

                      pop();
                      $('#notice').html('Client <b style="text-transform: capitalize;">'+myclient +'</b> has two (2) lots that were still reserved and are not yet paid.');
                  }  else {

                      pop();
                      $('#notice').html(data);
                  }  
              }
            });
        }
      } else if (myclid=='0') {

        $('#pop_bg').fadeIn('fast');
        $('#pop_c').slideDown('fast');
        $('#notice').fadeIn('fast');
        $('#notice').html('Please select a client!');
      } else {

        $('#pop_bg').fadeIn('fast');
        $('#pop_c').slideDown('fast');
        $('#notice').fadeIn('fast');
        $('#notice').html('Please add your client first! Click <a href="profile.php">here</a> and then select <b>My client(s)');
      }
});
```

Comment: Why use `live()`, that method was deprecated as of jQuery 1.7 (I think) and removed entirely from jQuery 1.9.

Comment: @user2053851 i tried your code but now it's not firing :/